# Reform wedding ceremony changes

Tags: halacha, minhag, wedding, reform-judaism

I saw a video of a Reform wedding ceremony, and noticed many differences between theirs and a traditional Orthodox ceremony.

1. *Sheva Berachos* were recited **before** *Kiddushin* (the giving of the ring)
2. No mention of a *Kesubah* (wasn't shown, signed, or read under the *chuppah*)
3. There were seemingly no witnesses designated or present (unless the parents/rabbi or something were considered witnesses)
4. *Birkas Erusin*, the blessing on Kiddushin, was said at the **end** of the ceremony

I'm just curious if other Reform weddings are like this, and if so why were these changes made? What did they accomplish? Were they purposeful changes, or just plain ignorance?

Something to note is the rabbi was reading from some sort of wedding ceremony book as he was reciting the prayers, etc. I didn't notice if he was flipping around, or if the book was presenting the parts in this particular order.

Comment: I assume there was a reform rabbi there who (according to them) would count as a witness, right?

Comment: These questions would be best asked to a reform Rabbi or Reform organization.  However, in general Reforms stance is that the Rabbi can make his own decisions and that may create different outcomes for each Rabbis decision .

Comment: Was this recent?  If so (3) might be COVID related and might not happen at normal weddings

Comment: @Heshy from the eighties. I don't think anyone is performing weddings these days